# How to extend a typescript class with a get property?

Tags: typescript

I get an instance of an object with say type `A`. How do I extend this with a getter function in Typescript? Adding a function I do

```
A.prototype.testFunction = function () {
  if(this.something) {
    return this.something;
  }
 return null;
}
```

I extend the type in an `index.d.ts` file such as:

```
interface A {
    testFunction (): SomeType|null;
}
```

But how am I supposed to add it if I want to to appear as a getter function, and not just as a function?

I tried looking at `Object.defineProperty()` but Typescript itself doesn't seem to be too happy working with that one, referring to the wrong instance of `this` in the following code:

```
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, "testGet", {
    get: function () {
        if(this.something) { // <== this appears to not refer to type A
          return this.something;
        }
        return null;
    },
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
});
```

Comment: `function()` declarations don't capture the `this` context, but arrow functions `=>` will. `testFunction = () => { do stuff }`  [See docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getters/setters can be declared simply as properties in interface:

```
interface A {
    testGet: SomeType|null;
}
```

And specify the [type of `this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) inside the getter function:

```
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, "testGet", {
    get (this: A) {
        if(this.something) { 
          return this.something;
        }
        return null;
    },
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I refer to `this` or the object in question in the defineProperty? It says it implicitly have type `any` (I have disallowed this in the tsconfig).

Comment: You can specify the type of `this` as a parameter to your getter. This will be erased during compilation.

Comment: How to put there generic type parameter ?